# Why doesn't deepcopy of a Pandas DataFrame affect memory usage?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
import resource
from copy import deepcopy

import pandas as pd
import random

n=100000
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(n)],
                   'y': [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(n)],
                   'z': [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(n)]
                   })
df2=deepcopy(df)
print 'memory peak: {kb} kb'.format(kb=resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)
```

I expect to see different memory peak usages for this code with the line `df2=deepcopy(df)`
 and without it. But the memory shows exactly the same result. 
Isn't `deepcopy` supposed to clone the object and therefore increase memory usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `copy.deepcopy` on an object `foo`, its `__dict__` is looked up for a `__deepcopy__` method, that is called in turn.
In the case of a `DataFrame` instance, it extends the `NDFrame` class, whose `__deepcopy__` method delegates the operation to `NDFrame.copy`.

Here's [the implementation of `NDFrame.__deepcopy__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L5844):

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memo=None):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    memo, default None
        Standard signature. Unused
    """
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
    return self.copy(deep=True)
```

You can read `NDFrame.copy`'s docstring [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L5733), but here's the main excerpt:

```
def copy(self, deep=True):
    """
    Make a copy of this object's indices and data.
    When ``deep=True`` (default), a new object will be created with a
    copy of the calling object's data and indices. Modifications to
    the data or indices of the copy will not be reflected in the
    original object (see notes below).
    (...)
    Notes
    -----
    When ``deep=True``, data is copied but actual Python objects
    will not be copied recursively, only the reference to the object.
    This is in contrast to `copy.deepcopy` in the Standard Library,
    which recursively copies object data (see examples below).
```

In your example, the data is Python lists, that are therefore not actually copied.

Comment: So the df2 is a shallow copy of df?

Comment: @InyoungKim As I understand it, the index is a deepcopy, but the data is not.

Comment: Looking at the bottom examples in the [Dataframe.copy() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html), it appears that the data *is* copied, just not recursively. The list/array for each column is copied, but if an item (cell) inside the dataframe is a Python object, it is not further (recursively) copied (and I assume that integers, as here, are always copied). See the last example, using a Series with a nested list. So I would actually expect the two dataframes from the question here to be fully independent.

Comment: @9769953 Yeah, actually I'm trying to wrap my head around that... I still don't get why the RAM is not doubled (which I confirmed using different tools, so I don't think there's any error here). Plus, the deepcopy is super fast, which is definitely wrong. I admit the list *do* look uncorrelated, but there cannot be deep copied without the memory doubling and in no time

Comment: My current best guess is overallocation by Python for its lists. Substracting some base memory for the Python runtime, there is very little increase seen when df is copied to df2. Doing this, however, with NumPy arrays (because `numpy.random.randint` is also a lot faster ;-), does show a noticeable increase (albeit it not twice) after the copy.

Comment: @9769953 I got it, it's some sort of copy on write. I cannot explain the exact mechanism, but the result of `deepcopy` is a shallow copy (which is necessary, because it's fast and it does not increase memory), and then, writing to that copy does increase the consumed memory. It's not visible with only one writing, and I cannot explain the pattern of this augmentation, but that's definitely something like that.

Comment: it would be good if your explanation in last comment will appear in the answer